# Map<K,V> to List for Dynamic Test in Java

Tags: java, collections, junit, java-stream

Background:
I'm trying to write a dynamic Test like:

```
    @TestFactory
Collection<DynamicTest> dynamicTestsFromCollection() {


    return Arrays.asList(
        dynamicTest("1st dynamic test", () -> assertTrue(true)),
        dynamicTest("2nd dynamic test", () -> assertEquals(4, 2 * 2))
    );
}
```

My Map contains `Map<String, List<Tuple4>>`

The key can have multiple "testfiles" which should be seen as ONE test.

but it can also have multiple keys for different "testcases".

What would be the best approach for this?

I thought converting it to a List and then construct my testcases from it.

**IMPORTANT** The Key - Value relationship may not be destructed, the order is not important.

Like

```
A    {FooForA, Foo2ForA, Foo3ForA}
B    {FooForB, Foo2ForB....}
```

The Values from Key B, may not get mixxed with Values for A.

Is this possible when converting to an List, since you only have one Element, how do you create the relationship. If this isn't safe im open for other Approaches like for example Streams or something else.

Here is some reference:
http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests

Comment: Wouldn't Map.entrySet() be useful? I'm not sure if I got what you want.

Comment: It’s not clear what you are talking about. You start with a `Map<String, List<Tuple4>>`, then say “the key can have multiple "testfiles"”—what key, the `String`? And what “testfiles” are you talking about? Then you proceed with “but it can also have multiple keys for different "testcases"”—what is “it”? And which testcases?